# How to print current directory name via MS-DOS commands

Tags: windows, command-line, command-prompt

I need to print current directory name after CD command.

Is it possible to do? Thanks!

```
echo off
echo. 
echo This batch program deletes some files  
echo. 

pause

cd "D:\Folder1\"  

pause
```

Comment: try cd with no arguments

Comment: @marc_s Windows 7 supports all those commands man! :)

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Just use `cd` with no arguments supplied. From `cd /?`:

> Type CD without parameters to display the current drive and directory.

Comment: And if you're trying to do more with the current directory as a value than simply printing it to console, use `%cd%` to access the environment variable.